# QGIS3: how to load SVG symbols

Tags: import, svg, qgis-3

For the record:  QGIS 3.2 and Mac OS 10.13.5

I am trying to load the symbols from https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/

I have tried creating `/Users/rful011/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg` (Which is the default path for sgv files that I copied from Preferences->Option->System) and copying the .svg files into the directory but I still don't see any more symbols in the style dialogue.    (edit: because I was looking in the wrong place).

Where should the files appear in the style dialogue?

I then tried "open library" button -> import/export -> import ... and navigated my way to the directory where the svg files are:

[image]

As one can see from the screenshot the files are not selectable in the finder window.

After a bit more research (reading the qgis3 symbol library doc) I tried renaming some of the svg files to .xml and they then became selectable in the finder but when I tried importing them I got a dialogue box with the message "An error occurred during import: Incorrect root tag in style: svg".

I am starting to conclude that QGIS is not expecting one to import .svg files this way. ( edit:  this is definitely not the way to do it.  THis is for simple markers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style manager contains symbol that are more complex than "simple" svg. For instance, you can have an svg whose color can be customized, and a symbol that uses this svg and sets the color to green and the size to 12.

The symbols are saved in a SQLlite DB, while the svg are files on disk.

To access the svg, you would need to declare the library path in `Settings ‣ Options ‣ System / svg paths`. The SVG are then available for styling under `marker / svg marker` or using the `+` icon in the style manager. After choosing one and customizing it, you can click `save` that will move it to the style manager.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I first tried after my initial research. Th first path in my question is the default path for sgv in preference, options, system.  I simply copied the files into the directory.  You mention and SQLite data base. How do the icons get loaded into it?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify

Comment: Turns out I was asking the wrong question.  The question should have been "how do I access svg markers in the style dialogue?"   I still have problems but I suspect this is another MacOS bug in QGIS3.   I am accepting this answer as it is correct for the question as posed.