# QGIS 3: How to access additional SVG symbols

Tags: qgis-3, svg

I want to create a map with a complex style and loaded a couple of additional SVG-libraries on my disk to the folder */usr/share/qgis/svg/* (I am on a Linux machine, running QGIS 3.10.1).

I have changed the SVG path in the options accordingly (see below) and even added another path to a certain subfolder, but still I can not find any of the SVG's in the styles menu to chose from.

[image]

I checked the forum history and didn't find anything on that problem appart from this post: [QGIS3: how to load SVG symbols](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288637/qgis3-how-to-load-svg-symbols?rq=1)

Apparently this user had the same problem, but it wasn't really solved for him either.

Comment: I just checked and it works using Windows 10.

Comment: As a work around can you put the SVG's in the default QGIS SVG folder?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto I tried that with different options (using subfolders and not using them etc.) but it did not work. Actually the default path as such did not exist (there was no folder ./svg in the ./locale folder of QGIS. I actually don't know, where QGIS takes its symbols from at the moment.

Comment: Try: /usr/share/qgis/svg

Comment: I did, as shown in the screenshot above.